# Aurora PostgreSQL fail over process

Tags: amazon-rds-aurora

Aurora PostgreSQL: How the process work on failover,I have a primary DB-prod for transaction database and read replica for reporting.
where reporting will be pointed if primary fail.

similar question on, "If I have a primary database and an Amazon Aurora Replica actively taking read traffic and a failover occurs, what happens?"  https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/

Answer (score 0):

The FAQ describes this fairly well.
https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/#If_I_have_a_primary_database_and_an_Amazon_Aurora_Replica_actively_taking_read_traffic_and_a_failover_occurs.2C_what_happens.3F

In your specific scenario:

1. apg-node-1 - current writer
2. apg-node-2 - current reader
3. apg-node-1 fails
4. AWS detects the failure and of apg-node-1 and initiates a failover to apg-node-2
5. The reads to apg-node-2 are briefly interrupted (low seconds)
6. The writer endpoint is re-directed to apg-node-2
7. If apg-node-1 is unavailable the reader endpoint continues to point to apg-node-2
8. Once apg-node-1 recovers the reader endpoint is re-directed to apg-node-1

These could be useful as well:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.BestPractices.FastFailover.html
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/failover-with-amazon-aurora-postgresql/

HTH.